# How to avoid duplication in spring security xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring, filter, spring-security

I have a spring security configuration XML which is full of repeated blocks like below. Note that the API pattern to which the security filters are applied varies but the filter chain is same for all such patterns.

How can I avoid repeating of writing same filter chain for each such block? i.e. Can the following two be combined in one block by some syntax? or maybe some XML tricks?

Moving it to java based WebConfiguration is not an option in this legacy app

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" pattern=“/foo/bar/”>
<security:headers>
    <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
</security:headers>
<security:intercept-url pattern=“foo/bar/” access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<security:custom-filter ref="apiSessionInvalidationFilter" after="DIGEST_AUTH_FILTER"/>
<security:custom-filter ref="oauth2RestAuthFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
<security:custom-filter ref="basicAuthFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
<security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>

<security:http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" pattern=“/tom/David/”>
    <security:headers>
        <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    </security:headers>
    <security:intercept-url pattern=“tom/*” access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="apiSessionInvalidationFilter" after="DIGEST_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="oauth2RestAuthFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="basicAuthFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend considering a migration from XML configuration to [Annotation Based Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360142/custom-webauthenticationdetails-programmatically-in-spring-security) you can find an example of migration.